# Glauberman-Thompson normal $p$-complement theorem for $p=2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, math-history

The following is Thompson’s normal $p$-complement theorem:

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $S$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup. Suppose that $p$ is odd or $G$ is $S_4$-free. Then $G$ has normal $p$-complement if and only if $C_G(Z(S))$ and $N_G(J(S))$ has normal $p$-complement.

The theorem in the original paper (Thompson, 1964) only gives the part of $p$ odd. Recall that a group is called $H$-free if no section of $G$ is isomorphic to $H$. In many later references, “$S_4$-free” is added in the statement. See for example (Huppert, 1967) and (Glauberman, 1971).

Another famous normal $p$-complement theorem is the one attributed to Glauberman-Thompson:

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $S$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup. Suppose that $p$ is odd. Then $G$ has normal $p$-complement if and only if $N_G(Z(J(S)))$ has normal $p$-complement.

I wonder if the $p=2$ part is valid for Glauberman-Thompson $p$-nilpotency criterion if the hypothesis “$S_4$-free” is added. But I could not find any $S_4$-free examples. Or can we do that with another functor like the one given by Stellmacher, that is, does the $p=2$ case follows immediately from any functor that admits a ZJ-type theorem?

Reference:

[1] Glauberman G. Global and local properties of finite groups. M.B. Powell and G. Higman, eds. Finite Simple Groups (Proc. Instructional Conf. Oxford, 1969). London: Academic Press, 1971, 1-64.

[2] Thompson J G. Normal $p$-complements for finite groups. J. Algebra, 1964, 43-46.

Comment: This question is probably more suitable for [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net)

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for your comment, Professor Holt. Do you have any clue about this question? I’m not sure if asking the same question in the two sites violates the rule of this community.

Comment: I haven't had time to think about it yet. It's OK to post on both sites provided that you include links in both posts to the other one to explain what you have done.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446473/glauberman-thompson-normal-p-complement-theorem-for-p-2

Comment: Next time, please follow Derek's suggestion to link the questions!